# Polynomial interpolation: Construct basis functions such that $\mu_j(L_k)=\delta_{jk}$

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

We are looking for the solution of the Hermitian-polynomial-interpolation with the data points $x_0=x_1=0, x_2=2, x_3=x_4=1.$

> Construct, analogous to the Lagrange-interpolation, basis functions $L_0,\ldots,L_4 \in \Pi_4$ such that $\mu_j(L_k)=\delta_{jk}$ for $j,k=0,\ldots,4.$

We defined $d_j=\max\{l:x_j=x_{j-l}\}$ and $\mu_j(f):=f^{(d_j)}(x_j)$.
And the Lagrange basis polynomials are defined as $L_j(x):=\prod_{k=0,k\neq j}^{n}\frac{x-x_k}{x_j-x_k}$.

So $d_0=0,d_1=1,d_2=0,d_3=0,d_4=1$.

What do I have to do now? Determine $L_k$ and see if they  satisfy $\mu_j(L_k)=\delta_{jk}$? And what do I have to do if they dont satisfy this? I don't really understand the task.

Comment: If $n\ge 2$, the formulae you give for $L_j(x)$ $(j=0,...,n)$ only make sense if $x_0,...,x_n$ are $n+1$ $distinct$ values. Otherwise for some $j,$ some denominator $x_j-x_k$ is $0$.

Comment: Yes I noticed that but that's the definition of the Lagrange basis polynomials. I don't know how I should construct such basis functions. I thought about including $x_j \neq x_k$ but maybe I need a completely different formula - I don't really know what my professor meant with 'analogous to Lagrange interpolation'

Comment: I think you should ask your prof for a clarification.